# how to add target build in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I currently have an Android project in Eclipse.
I need to change target build in Project properties 
but there is only Android 4.4 in the list
how can i add another target ? for example 2.1 or 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the list it only shows the SDKs that you have installed. If you want to build application with a specific version then in SDK manager download the SDK first and then use that for making a build.

Generally we make build only with the latest version. Why do you want to make a build with other version? If you want to support older version like 2.2 then you have to set that in minSdkVersion in your manifest file.

Comment: tnx mr sharj i found it